# Laravel Query Builder select return columns inside an array

Tags: arrays, laravel, select, eloquent

I have a query like this:

```
$task_query = DB::table('table_a')
            ->join('materials', 'table_a.material_id', '=', 'materials.id')
            ->join('products', 'table_a.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select(
                'table_a.colum_1',
                'table_a.colum_2',
                'table_a.colum_3',
                'materials.colum_1 as material_column_1',
                'materials.colum_2 as material_column_2',
                'materials.colum_3 as material_column_3',
                'products.colum_1 as product_column_1',
                'products.colum_2 as product_column_2',
                'products.colum_3 as product_column_3',
            )
            ->when( some conditions )
            ->get();
```

This query return a flat result with all columns I want. But, I need a way to group some columns into  sub-arrays like this:

```
$task_query = DB::table('table_a')
            ->join('materials', 'table_a.material_id', '=', 'materials.id')
            ->join('products', 'table_a.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select(
                'a' => [
                        'table_a.colum_1',
                        'table_a.colum_2',
                        'table_a.colum_3',
                ],
                'material' => [
                        'materials.colum_1',
                        'materials.colum_2',
                        'materials.colum_3',
                ],
                'product' => [
                        'products.colum_1',
                        'products.colum_2',
                        'products.colum_3',
                ],
            )
            ->when( some conditions )
            ->get();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: why dont you take the data and build and array after that

Comment: foreach /  !in_array

Comment: @ReubenGomes, It's better if I can do it once inside the query. If I build arrays after query, it's complicated. I'll spent too many  "if - elseif - else / in_array" statements to put every column into $array_a or $array_m or $array_p.

Comment: @brombeer, Thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: @QuangNguyen sql cant get you data as an array youll have to build your own array post that

Comment: or go the unconventional route  and get your primary data and then inside loop fire sql queries

Comment: i dont recommend this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL cannot get you the structure you want as far as I know. But you can use `map()` to restructure your data from your first query.

```
$data = $task_query->map(function($task) {
    return [
        'a' => [$task->column_1, $task->column_2, $task->column_3],
        'material' => [$task->material_column_1, $task->material_column_2, $task->material_column_3],
        'product' => [$task->product_column_1, $task->product_column_2, $task->product_column_3]
    ];
});
```

Then you can use your data in your structure

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    $item['a'];
    $item['material'];
    $item['product'];
}
```